# How do I disable the "undo code cleanup?" prompt in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: prompt, undo, code-cleanup, disable, jetbrains-rider

My team has configured ReSharper/Rider to automatically run code-cleanup every time we save.  I save a lot, which means code-cleanup runs a lot.  Every time I try to Ctrl+Z past a point where code-cleanup ran, Rider prompts me with a pop-up asking if I really want to undo.

Is there a way I can disable this prompt?  It's very annoying to move my hand from my keyboard to my mouse every time just to click "yes".  I wouldn't have pressed Ctrl+Z in the first place if I didn't want to undo.

To be clear: I'm *not* trying to disable automatic code-cleanup on save.

I have already tried goolging this question.  The only answers I found were about code-cleanup itself, not about disabling the confirmation upon undoing it.

Comment: I don't have a solution to this issue, but it feels like a relatively new behavior in Rider. I filed a feature request to add an option to auto-dismiss that modal. 
If you're like me and you landed on this page because you were googling for a solution, maybe give that issue an upvote:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-88903/Add-option-to-auto-accept-Undo-Code-Cleanup-modal